# How To Open Android App Activity automatically on receiving notification Using Php FCM

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

I have to launch the app on receiving notifications. The following piece of code works fine when the app is killed and notification is received. But I want When Notification received App Open Automatically Without Click On Notification. App Lunch Automatically in all cases if my mobile is locked too.
**Please Help Me**. Here Is My Code.

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG="PushNotification";
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "101";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createNotificationChannel();
        subscribeToTopic();
        getToken();
    }

    private void getToken()
    {
       FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
               if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                   Log.d(TAG,"OnComplete: Faileed to get the Token");
               }
               String token=task.getResult();
               Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + token);
           }
       });
    }
    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "firebaseNotifChannel";
            String description = "Receve Firebase notification";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    private void subscribeToTopic() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("resulttime")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**MyFireBaseServices.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseServices extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG ="PushNotification";
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "101";


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    private void showNotification(String title,String message){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Result.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_24)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

        // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.link.fcmpuchtest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FcmPuchTest">
        <activity android:name=".Result"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseServices">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**My Php Code Is**

```
<?php

function notify($to,$data){

    $api_key="AAAAjW65hDI:APA91bE4cXuCdMf9pPDVHqjjpjelkjirj']9099hUqOX0SOXzi5GEc3mdPwRqsG8bgqz0S3EnpoQtWCaj2_wbF39I57Tyxo4EAeJ2pSo_IVJPc_fQp7hiuNFGYTjkbnJHUIOK7HTioU";
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    $url="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    
    $fields=json_encode(array('to'=>$to,'notification'=>$data));

    // Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
    

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($fields));

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: key ='.$api_key;
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}

$to="/topics/resulttime";
$data=array(
    'title'=>'Greetings Result',
    'body'=>'Hi, From PHP Script'
);

notify($to,$data);
echo "Notification Sent";

?>
```

**I have Already Use This Code But Not Working**

```
    @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```